# Backbone destroy error

Tags: backbone.js

When I call the backbone destroy method on a model i'm getting this error.

> A "url" property or function must be specified

I'm using a local collection and I saw online somewhere that the save method is called in the destroy method which looks for a url. Is there away around this. How can I prevent the error from happening.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The purpose of the `destroy` method is to delete the model *on the server*.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the model in a collection but I don't have access to the collection from the code I'm in. I thought destroy would work but its causing an error because the model doesn't have url. So I'm trying to find a solution to this. Is there a way to get the collection a model is in from the model itself.

Comment: Collections do have a `remove` method.

Comment: Ah, you don't have a reference to the collection containing the model (edit)

Comment: Right I'm aware of the remove but as I said I don't have access to the collection itself. so I can't just call collection.remove(model)

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't explain it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `nrabinowitz` said in the comment, destroy is for removing from the server and won't actually remove from the collection as it is.

If the problem is removing it from the collection as it seems in the comments...

A model has access to it's collection via the `collection` property of the model.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{ name: 'bob' }
    }),
    Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Model
    });

var c = new Collection([{ name: 'joe'}, {name: 'h'}, {name: 'bob'}]);

var m = c.at(1); // get model at index 1 name = h

m.collection.remove( m ); // access the collection via the model we pulled out

console.log( c.length ); // only 2 models within :)
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/Pn2Vw/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I didn't realize that Models had this collection attribute.

I was curious about what happens when a Model is added to multiple Collections, so I checked the [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-81), and found that Collection._prepareModel will set the Model's collection attribute. Thus, if the same Model is added into multiple Collections, its collection attribute will point to the last one to which it was added.

Comment: Also, I believe that your statement that "[destroy] won't actually remove from the collection as it is" is incorrect. Per [Model.destroy source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-59) and [Collection._onModelEvent source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-105), Collections will react to a "destroy" event triggered on the model. One note: the collection argument passed with the destroy event reflects the model's collection attribute, _not_ necessarily the collection forwarding the event onto any of its listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My problem was that I used the destroy callback to determine whether remove the model from the coollection or not:

```
this.model.destroy({
  success: function(model, response)  {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

That, testing with returning `Error 500` from server, I got the same error on **the second time I tried to call destroy**.

The solution came from [the manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy). Looks like although I didn't call `this.remove();`, the model was removed from the collection:

> Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server to respond before removing the model from the collection.

The result looks like that:

```
this.model.destroy({
  wait: true,
  success: function(model, response)  {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```